# Unable to print the string (C++)

Tags: c++, string, c++14

I am unable to print the string after assigning every value of one string to another string. How to overcome this problem

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, k;
  string s = "Nikhil", shiftedS;
  n = s.length();
  cin >> k;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    int idx = (i + k) % n;
    shiftedS[idx] = s[i];
  }
  shiftedS[n] = '\0';

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << shiftedS[i] << " ";
  cout << shiftedS; // I am unable to print when I try like this.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accessing the element at index `>= s.length()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also -- C++ string doesn't treat `\0` specially.

Comment: #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s="Nikhil",shiftedS;
    int n,k;
    k=s.length();
    cout<<"Enter how many elements you want to shift ";
    cin>>k;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        int idx=(i+k)%n;
        shiftedS[idx]=s[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<shiftedS[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
This is the actual program where i want to use it

Comment: To shift the characters of a string

Comment: Then you have to `resize` it first. Also -- [edit] the question if you want to add more information.

Comment: Also -- there is `string::substr`.

Comment: I edited the question.I think now you can understand my problem clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166609/discussion-between-bijjala-naga-nikhil-and-user202729).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting unpredictable behavior because `shiftedS` is an empty string. If you initialize it like this

```
string shiftedS(n, ' ');    // n is equal to length of "Nikhil"
```

and get rid of `shiftedS[n] = '\0';` (C++ string object doesn't need this), it should work as expected. I tried it out with these changes and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try like this

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n,k;
string s="Nikhil",shiftedS = "";
n=s.length();
cin>>k;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int idx=(i+k)%n;
    shiftedS+=s[i];
}
cout<<shiftedS;
return 0;
}
```